# Sending multiple drop down selections as php variables

Tags: php, forms

I'm fairly new to PHP and am working on building an event attendance planner for a friend. I've spent quite a lot of time looking for similar scenario's, but nothing I've found quite fits what I'm trying to do.

Event locations and dates are pulled from a database without issue, and I have a "yes/no/maybe" drop down box next to each so users can indicate their attendance preferences. I intend to send the form output to a second page for validation, then insertion into a new database table once checked.

```
<form action="process.php" name ="attending" method="POST">
 <?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
 //Query the database for events this year
$wquery = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE YEAR(date4) = YEAR(CURDATE())";
 // Echo results
$result = $conn->query($wquery);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["startdate"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["enddate"]; ?></td>
    <td><b><?php echo $row["eventlocation"]; ?></b></td>
<?php
//create a variable to store the value of the drop down 
    if (empty($attending)){$attending = "";};
//create drop down options
?>                                    
<td>
Attending?
<select id="<?php '$eventid?>_<?php $attending'?>" name="attending">
  <option value="Select...">Select...</option>
  <option value= "Yes">Yes</option>
  <option value= "No">No</option>
    <option value= "Maybe">Maybe</option>
</select>
    </td><br>
        <br>
  </tr>
<?php
};  
    ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

I'm currently dumping the output on process.php with "php var_dump($_POST)" for now, just so it can be checked by eye. It's displaying on the page before submission absolutely fine, but even though I have a dozen test events, the output I get is a single line stating "array(2) { ["attending"]=> string(9) "Select..." ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }"

It's something to do with how I'm trying to give each response its own unique key by mixing the event ID with their response but I just can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. Probably very obvious for someone with a bit more experience, so if anyone can give me a nudge in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: You create multiple dropdowns... but all with the same name ;) Try `name="attending[]"` as the name of the select

Comment: And access them as a array $_POST['attending'][0], $_POST['attending'][1] and os on